# How to rotate an UIImage but dont cut the edges IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgcontextdrawimage

Help, Im new to ios programming, I want to rotate may UIImage but I dont want the edges to be cut or loose some part of the image.

this is my code:

```
double angle = M_PI * 10/ 180; CGSize s = {image.size.width, image.size.height}; UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(s); CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2);

transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(ctx,CGRectMake(-[image size].width/2,-[image size].height/2,image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

The image is rotating but the size of the frame does not change because of that some of the image has been cut.

OUTPUT:https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/1555286_761679470521535_1800180000235265553_n.jpg

EXPECTED OUTPUT: https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t1.0-0/10314770_761675840521898_6536715783383115855_a.jpg

Please help me thank you.

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want and what you get. It's hard to assess from the code.

Comment: sorry cant post image right now this is the link, OUTPUT: https://scontent-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t1.0-9/10505458_761675820521900_8470585883834730404_n.jpg                  EXPECTED OUTPUT: https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t1.0-0/10314770_761675840521898_6536715783383115855_a.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you are searching for.

Just copy the following code at the end of the `.m` file (after the `@end`) in which you want to rotate an image.

```
@interface UIImage (RotationMethods)
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees;
@end

@implementation UIImage (RotationMethods)

static CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};

- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees 
{   
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Then rotate your image like in the example below:

```
CGFloat degrees = 90;
yourImage = [yourImage imageRotatedByDegrees:degrees];
```